# What connection string for .NET 4.0, EF 4.4 and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, connection-string

I get several different errors when I try to publish my website on hosting services. All seems related to my connection string and my provider. I use Entity Framework with MySQL database. EF 4.4.0.0 with .NET 4.0.

First I would like to know if the syntax of this connection string is correct. Is it correct to have a name, a connectionString and a providerName ?

```
<add name="MyName" 
connectionString="
  metadata=res://*/MusicModel.csdl|res://*/MusicModel.ssdl|res://*/MusicModel.msl;
  provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
  provider connection string=&quot;
  server=www.myserver.net;
  user id=Music;
  password=Wff8F99SNkiRi0;
  database=Music&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Depending on the hosting service I get these kind of error message:

- The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
  message is 'The underlying provider failed on Open.'. See server logs
  for more details.
- The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
  message is 'The specified store provider cannot be found in the
  configuration, or is not valid.'. See server logs for more details.

I have no more details in my server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<add name="modelEntities"
  connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;
  provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
  provider connection string='server=mysql.server.ext;
    User Id=mysqluser;
    Persist Security Info=True;
    database=mysqldb;
    password=mysqlpwd'"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
/>
```

use it like provider connection string='..' instead of provider connection string="...."
Or u can simply use like

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
         invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
         description="Data Provider for MySQL"
         type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

and

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ChinookContext"
        connectionString=
"server=localhost;database=Chinook;User Id=root;password=P4ssw0rd"
        providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I get a Column 'InvariantName' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is already present. error now